# python 3.5 -> 3.6 Tablib TypeError: cell() missing 1 required positional argument: 'column'

Tags: python, django, python-3.6, django-import-export, tablib

Migrating from python 3.5 to 3.6, my unit tests reveal a problem with django-import-export & tablib:

TypeError: cell() missing 1 required positional argument: 'column'

```
File "<path>/lib/python3.6/site-packages/tablib/formats/_xlsx.py", line 122, in dset_sheet
    cell = ws.cell('%s%s' % (col_idx, row_number))
    TypeError: cell() missing 1 required positional argument: 'column'
```

The line in tablib:

```
    cell = ws.cell('%s%s' % (col_idx, row_number))
```

So indeed, there is no argument for the column

My view code:

```
my_resource = MyModelResource(queryset=my_queryset)
dataset = my_resource.export()
response = HttpResponse(dataset.xlsx, content_type='application/vnd.ms-excel')
```

This works fine in python3.5 but fails under 3.6

requirements.txt:

```
...
tablib==0.12.1
django-import-export==0.7.0
Django==1.11.7
...
```

Answer (score 34, accepted):

This has nothing to do with Python 3.5 or 3.6. You have a newer `openpyxl` version installed with your 3.6 installation compared to your 3.5 setup.

The version you have installed with 3.6 has [removed the *deprecated coordinate parameter from `worksheet.cell()` method*](https://bitbucket.org/openpyxl/openpyxl/commits/93e2189522fd2f8e14c3d5bcba045caa4ecddde5) and [made the *`row` and `column` mandatory arguments*](https://bitbucket.org/openpyxl/openpyxl/commits/d66c74fdd55ac699865ee5f7dff9bd483c2590fb). This is part of [version 2.5.0b1](https://openpyxl.readthedocs.io/en/latest/changes.html#b1-2017-10-19), released on 2018-01-19 (two weeks ago):

> #### Major Changes
>
> `worksheet.cell()` no longer accepts a coordinate parameter. The syntax is now `ws.cell(row, column, value=None)`

The `tablib` library has not yet adjusted to this change. The code should just pass in the column and row numbers directly:

```
cell = ws.cell(row=row_number, column=col_idx)
```

Using keyword arguments would ensure compatibility all the way back to 1.1.0 (the release that added support for the `column` and `row` parameters, released in 2010).

In the meantime, you can downgrade your `openpyxl` installation to version 2.4.9, the last release without those changes.

Also see [issue #324](https://github.com/kennethreitz/tablib/issues/324) in the `tablib` project repository.

Comment: Great answer. Adding openpyxl==2.4.9 to the requirements.txt file indeed fixes this issue.

Comment: Excellent thanks! I hope this is not the beginning of the end for the awesomest tablib package.